# Constructor Overloading Ambiguity When Trying to Support Literals

Tags: c++, class, constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

### Code

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
class MyContainer
{
private:
    Type contained;
public:
    MyContainer<Type>(Type & a): contained(a) { std::cout << "&\n"; }
    MyContainer<Type>(Type   a): contained(a) { std::cout << "_\n"; }
};

class Epidemic
{
private:
    int criticality;
public:
    Epidemic(int c): criticality(c);
};

int main()
{
    // using objects //
    Epidemic ignorance(10);
    MyContainer<Epidemic> testtube(ignorance); // should print "&"; error instead

    // using primitive //
    double irrationalnumber = 3.1415;
    MyContainer<double> blasphemousnumber(irrationalnumber); // should print "&"; error instead

    // using literal //
    MyContainer<double> digits(123456789.0); // prints "_"
}
```

---

### Description

`MyContainer<Type>(Type & a)` is meant for most everything. However, it won't work with literals (e.g. `1.732`). That's why I added a `MyContainer<Type>(Type a)`. However, by adding this, I end up with an ambiguity because non-literals can use either constructor.

---

### Question

> **Is there a way to satisfy all parameters (both literal and non-literal) given to a constructor?**

Comment: `MyContainer<Type>(const Type&   a)` instead of the value type?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ & jrok -- Yes, thank you both! It works now. Is it because under the hood, literals (in the case of a `int` literal) are `const int`s? That would make sense, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change from the value type parameter to a `const` reference:

```
template <typename Type>
class MyContainer
{
private:
    Type contained;
public:
    MyContainer<Type>(Type & a): contained(a) { std::cout << "&\n"; }
    MyContainer<Type>(const Type& a): contained(a) { std::cout << "_\n"; }
                   // ^^^^^     ^
};
```

Comment: Does this also mean I can remove the first constructor (given that I don't change the argument in the constructor)?

Comment: @SirJony Yes, as long you don't want to change the input parameter. I already wondered why you wanted to distinguish the cases.